# C# - Sorting a list when it has more than one value per 'row'?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

Exception: Failed to compare two elements in the array.

```
private void assignNames(DropDownList ddl, Hashtable names)
{
    List<ListItem> nameList = new List<ListItem>();
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        ddl.ClearSelection();
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select Author"));
        foreach (string key in names.Keys)
        {
            nameList.Add(new ListItem(names[key].ToString(), key));

        }

    nameList.Sort();
}
```

So how can I use Sort() to compare on the "names" and not get stuck on the key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Provide a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) to instruct the [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) on how to sort the items.

```
nameList.Sort(delegate(ListItem thisItem, ListItem otherItem) {
    return thisItem.Text.CompareTo(otherItem.Text);
});
```

You might also want to check for `null` to be complete, unless you already know there won't be any, as in this case.

Comment: You could also use a lambda expression instead of the anonymous delegate, if you'd prefer and can use .NET 3.5.

Comment: Just curious, how would you do this in VB.NET?

Comment: nameList.Sort(Function(thisItem as ListItem, otherItem as ListItem) return ...)

Comment: There's no `Return` in VB lambda syntax, though. It's just `Function(x, y) x.Text.CompareTo(y.Text)` - and you do not need types for arguments, as they're deduced.

Answer (score 3):

nameList=nameList.OrderBy(li => li.Text).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

what type of object is "names"?

EDIT:
From what I can tell you will have to specify an IComparer for this to work, not sure if I fully understand what you are trying to do though.

EDIT:
This is way too complicated for what I "feel" your intent is, you basically want to populate a dropdown list with a sorted list of Author names.

you should be able to have a

```
List<string> auhtorNames;
authorNames.Sort();
ddl.DataSource = authorNames;
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList.Sort(IComparer) instead of ArrayList.Sort().

Answer (score 0):

ListItem is not Comparable. you could use a System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary instead.